# Split database: where are queries located and how to view SQL?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I'm redeveloping an Access + VB based application to C# and SQL server. I am working with the split versions of the Access database. In the front-end file when in design view I see code like this for some event routines to lookup a value from a query:

`DLookup("someField", "someQuery")`

This is probably simple but I cannot find where "someQuery" and queries in general are located and how to view them. They don't appear in the backend file and I can't see how to list them in the front end file. I haven't had any luck searching the net only that [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/access-help/split-an-access-database-HA010342026.aspx) suggests they are located in the front end file. How can I view the SQL for these queries?

Comment: On the Navigation pane in the front end db, click the drop down arrow next to `All Access Objects` and make sure `All Access Objects` is checked.  In case the queries have been set as hidden, right-click that same header and choose `Navigation Options`, then check `Show Hidden Objects`.  If that still doesn't display the queries in the Navigation Pane, we'll have to go hardcore.  But check those settings first.

Comment: @HansUp, thanks for the help, however the navigation panel is not available when I open the front-end and clicking on start does not give an option to make the nav panel visible as followed [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/access-help/show-or-hide-the-navigation-pane-HA010235717.aspx#BM2).

Comment: @HansUp Nope, does nothing.

Comment: Create a new empty database file.  Try to import queries from the front end into the new database.  At least that should show you whether there are any queries to import.

Comment: @HansUp, thanks for your help that did it, new file -> import queries from old. Put an answer in for your reward ;-)

Comment: OK, I did it.  There is an Access option, "Use Access Special Keys" ... if you add a check for that option, you should be able to use `F11` to open the Navigation Pane.  However, if it won't let you set the option to display the Navigation Pane, perhaps it won't permit you to allow special keys, either.  :-(

Comment: @HansUp can't find "Use Access Special Keys" MS Office button gives only a close db option. Perhaps disabled during the split? I only need to read the SQL so a query import does the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are unable to open the Navigation Pane, you could create a new db file and import queries from the front end into the new db (see the Import section of the External Data ribbon).  Without the linked tables, those queries will be non-functional, but that effort will allow you to identify which queries exist and you may examine their SQL if that is helpful.

You could even create links to the back end tables and import anything else you may need from the front end db.